# Error performing query operation Wait time of the request to the service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I am using the arcgis server 11.1 version. I have published the Map services and trying to query it through a rest endpoint. It used to work earlier but now started failing. I am trying to send a query it returns the below error.

*Error performing query operation Wait time of the request to the service `MapserviceName` has expired.*

Comment: There are a number of things I would check.  The timeout comes from the service properties, defined in the pooling settings in ArcGIS Server Manager.  You can change the timeout settings to a higher value.  However, if all was working before the upgrade, it could the registered data store.  I would check that your registered connection can still validate.  Are you seeing the issue on all services, or just one? Have you tried republishing the service? What parameters are you passing to the query operation?